# Javascript / generate random number after decimal

Tags: javascript

As an example I would like to get values between 32.2000 and 32.2999

I assume it would be something similar to

```
(Math.random() + 32.2).toFixed(4)
```

but it seems to generate any value between 32.xxxx and 33.xxxx

Am I making an obvious error on my end or is it more complex than I initially assumed?

Comment: This is not a duplicate as it is a particular range starting with a static number before the decimal

Comment: Yes it is. `console.log(
  (Math.random() * (32.2999 - 32.2000) + 32.2000).toFixed(4)
)`

Comment: Sigh, thought I tried that at one point but I accidentally put a plus instead of a times after Math.random, which is what threw me off. Got it now, thanks!